# Graph type taxonomy

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to create a taxonomy of graph (a.k.a networks) types. Here what I came with so far. I would like to have comments from mathematicians to get feedback on this classification. Please feel free to suggest important missing categories. Note that some types may belong to several categories. Thank you in advance.

Please note: while I am receiving the comments, I am updating the hierarchy in the question.

- Hypergraph

  - KUniformHypergraph

    - Graph

      - AcyclicGraph

        - SimpleGraph
        - Forest
        - SimpleDirectedGraph

          - DirectedLabeledGraph
        - Tree
      - ConnectedGraph

        - Tree
      - DirectedGraph

        - SimpleDirectedGraph
        - DirectedLabeledGraph
      - DisconnectedGraph

        - Forest
      - KPartiteGraph

        - BipartiteGraph
      - NonSimpleGraph

        - CyclicGraph
        - Multigraph
      - PlanarGraph
      - SimpleGraph

        - Forest
        - SimpleDirectedGraph

          - DirectedLabeledGraph
        - Tree
      - UndirectedGraph
      - WeightedGraph

Comment: You have forest in multiple places, and none of them seem very good.  A forest is a not-necessarily connected graph where each connected component is a tree.  So I'd assume it is under disconnected, not connected (unless you mean necessarily disconnected, which probably isn't a very good category).  The categories in general aren't very disjoint.

Comment: I would start with real disjoint, complete classification (like undirected/directed), and then start refining from there (underneath the categories, not as additional categories!).

Comment: @exodus5 Yes good catch. Forest should be a disconnected graph as it is a collection of tree (connected graph)

Comment: I am using description logic to perform this classification (using OWL). Not all graphs are directed or undirected. (example hypergraph). Acyclic and cyclic graph are not subclassed of directed or undirected graphs. I needed to introduce them as separate concepts.

Comment: @exodus5 I updated the taxonomy based on your comment

Comment: "bipartite" is an important one that's missing. "planar" is another.

Comment: @Gerry I updated the taxonomy by adding kPartiteGraph with the bipartiteGraph as subclass. I also added PlanarGraph. Can hypergraph be planar graph ?

Comment: Apparently there is a notion of planarity for hypergraphs: x0.no/atod

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Graph? Are multiple edges or loops allowed?

Aren't graphs a special case of digraphs and not the other way around? Ie. a graph is a digraph $(N,A)$ s.t. $(a,b)\in A$ iff $(b,a)\in A$.

I also think that hypergraphs are a superclass of graphs and not the other way around.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to check: http://x0.no/atof

Comment: @fidc Yes my graph definition allows multiple edges or loops. Digraphs are in my understanding a specialization of graph (containing directed edges). I am reflecting your suggestion to have hypergraph as superclass of graph in my question. Thank you for your input

Comment: Can we now see your updated taxonomy?

Comment: @Ron The latest update is reflected in my question