# Taxonomic relationship between hypergraph and graph

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

I am trying to build a [taxonomy of graph types](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318260/graph-type-taxonomy). A hypergraph is often defined as a generalization of a graph. Its edges (called hyperedge) can have more then 2 endpoints. From a taxonomic view point, is an hypergraph a superclass of graph or is it a subclass ? If an hypergraph is a subclass of graph, what would be called the category of graphs with only simple edges (2 endpoint edges) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a hypergraph as a pair $\mathcal{H}=(V,\mathcal{E})$, where $\mathcal{E}\subseteq 2^{V}$. When all the edges have the same size, say $k$, this is $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\binom{V}{k}$, then $\mathcal{H}$ is called a $k$-uniform hypergraph.

Using the notation from above graphs would correspond to 2-uniform hypergraphs. You can further restrict to graphs not having multiple edges, ie. simple graphs. Two exotic names for these are 2-uniform simple hypergraphs or 2-uniform linear hypergraphs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the  [taxonomy](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318260/graph-type-taxonomy) of graph types accordingly